# Apache Superset - Unable to find superset folder in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-superset

I have a problem where I couldn't find superset installation folder after I installed superset from this link https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html

Where is the folder?

Comment: Find you active python by running `which python`. If you python is from anaconda , then the package will be present in the `site-packages` of anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Superset in the Anaconda base environment (on Ubuntu). The install files are in:

*~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset*

This of course depends on the location of your Anaconda installation. So it would be:

*~/anaconda_installation_location/lib/python3.7/site-packages/superset*

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Apache Superset using python and the virtualenv. For me, I found the superset files in :

*/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/superset/*

Also, the frontend assets were found in :

*/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/superset/static/assets/src/*

I hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of dist-packages look for site-packages

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, here's the path on ***Windows*** you can find superset at -

> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\superset

Answer (score 0):

Using docker it will get the destination while cloning from git itself.

**In Virtual environment**
In the file explorer type \wsl$ in the address bar and click enter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96L3U.png)

It display the virtual environment.
home/user/venv(virtualEnvironmentName)/lib/python/site-packages/superset